# For any function $f$ that is a "polynomial in $x$", an equivalent representation of $f$ can be made such that it is, instead, a "polynomial in $x-k$"

Tags: calculus, polynomials, solution-verification

Sorry for the awkward phrasing of the post title. Here is precisely what I am interested in proving:

> For any $n$-degree polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ and for any non-zero $k \in \mathbb R$, there exists a collection $b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_{n-1},b_n$ such that $f(x)=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0$.

I am wondering if my below argument is acceptable. I was having some trouble deciding whether or not I needed induction to formally prove the statement ( I decided *against* incorporating induction).

The book I am working in is specific to single variable calculus (no linear algebra has been taught).

---

Consider an arbitrary $n$-the degree polynomial of the form:

$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$

Let us reframe the question as determining whether the following set is empty:$\displaystyle \left\{B \in \mathbb R^{n+1} | a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0\right\}$.

Working from $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0$, we can find each $b_{j}$ using the following procedure:

1. Take the $j$th derivative of both sides
2. Evaluate both sides at $x=k$
3. The resulting expression will be of the following form:

\begin{align}b_j( j !)&= (n)\times(n-1) \times \cdots \times(n-j+1)\times a_nk^{n-j}\\&+(n-1)\times(n-2)\times \cdots \times(n-1-j+1)\times a_{n-1} k^{n-1-j}+\cdots\\&+(j+1)\times (j)\times \cdots \times 2 \times a_{j+1}k^1+j\times(j-1)\times\cdots\times1 \times a_j k^0\\&=\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}a_nk^{n-j}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-j)!}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}+\cdots\\&+\frac{(j+1)!}{(j+1-j)!}a_{j+1}k^{j+1-j}+\frac{j!}{(j-j)!}a_jk^{j-j}\end{align}

Which simplifies to:

\begin{align}b_j&=\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}a_nk^{n-j}+\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}a_{n-1}k^{n-j-1}+\cdots\\&+\frac{(j+1)!}{j!(j+1-j)}a_{j+1}k+\frac{j!}{j!(j-j)!}a_j\end{align}

Of course, many of of these terms conform to the structure of a binomial coefficient, so we can further simplify to:

$$b_j={n\choose j}a_nk^{n-j}+{n-1\choose j}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}+\cdots+{j+1\choose j}a_{j+1}k+{j\choose j}a_j$$

All of the $a_i$ are given to us, so each $b_j$ can be calculated accordingly.

---

Edit:

After some additional thought, I would like to challenge *Martin R*'s claim that my proof is correct (at least, it is not correct in the rigorous sense). Although I received no outside clarification in a follow up post I made ( [Clarifying which instances constitute begging the question when reasoning backwards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832040/clarifying-which-instances-constitute-begging-the-question-when-reasoning-backwa) ), it is clear to me that the proof I submitted above is implicitly acceptable...but *not* explicitly acceptable.

In order to understand why this is true, first note that the expressions: $f(x)=g(x-k)$ is *logically equivalent* to $f(x+k)=g(x)$. Next, note that the claim we are trying to prove is something like:

> For any $n$-degree polynomial $f$ with coefficients $A \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ and for any $k \in \mathbb R$, there exists a collection of coefficients $B \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb R: a_n(x+k)^n+a_{n-1}(x+k)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(x+k)+a_0=b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0$.

Using a purposefully dumbed-down logic shorthand, the claim is basically structured as: $\varphi(f,A,k,n) \implies \exists B:\psi(B, f, A, k, n)$. In English, if function $f$ satisfies the relevant $\varphi$ properties related to $A, k, $ and $n$, then we can conclude that a $B$ exists that satisfies the $\psi$ property. In my proof, I actually *started with* the $\exists B:\psi(B, f, k, A, n)$ claim, and then I go on to derive a new claim about $B$...call it $\theta(B,k,A,n)$. In and of itself, this is **not** formally acceptable.

There is a type of logical argument known as *backwards reasoning*. Using this strategy, if someone is interested in proving $A \implies D$, they may start from $D$ and only use biconditional arguments to trace our way back to $A$...i.e. $D \iff C \iff B \iff A$. Because of the biconditional nature of the claims, we then have $A \implies B \implies C \implies D$.

In order for my argument to be logically correct, I need to show that $\theta(B,k,A,n) \implies \psi(B, f, k, A, n)$. This is essentially what Martin R argued in his proof.

Consider our $\theta(B,k,A,n)$ claim:

\begin{align} b_n&={n\choose n}a_n k^{n-n}\\b_{n-1}&={n\choose n-1}a_n k^{n-(n-1)}+ {n-1\choose n-1}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-1)}\\b_{n-2}&={n\choose n-2}a_nk^{n-(n-2)}+{n-1\choose n-2}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-2)}+{n-2\choose n-2}a_{n-2}k^{n-2-(n-2)}\\b_{n-3}&={n\choose n-3}a_nk^{n-(n-3)}+{n-1\choose n-3}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-3)}+{n-2\choose n-3}a_{n-2}k^{n-2-(n-3)}+{n-3\choose n-3}a_{n-3}k^{n-3-(n-3)}\\&\cdots\end{align}

Hopefully, you can see the pattern that occurs vertically if we were to list out all of these $b_j$. Specifically, if we take the column of all $a_n$, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_nk^{n-j}$. If we take the column of all $a_{n-1}$, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}$...etc. Now, consider what happens if we multiply each $b_j$ expression by $x^j$:

\begin{align} b_n\times x^n&=\left[{n\choose n}a_n k^{n-n}\right]\times x^n\\b_{n-1}\times x^{n-1}&=\left[{n\choose n-1}a_n k^{n-(n-1)}+ {n-1\choose n-1}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-1)}\right]\times x^{n-1}\\b_{n-2}\times x^{n-2}&=\left[{n\choose n-2}a_nk^{n-(n-2)}+{n-1\choose n-2}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-2)}+{n-2\choose n-2}a_{n-2}k^{n-2-(n-2)}\right]\times x^{n-2}\\b_{n-3}\times x^{n-3}&=\left[{n\choose n-3}a_nk^{n-(n-3)}+{n-1\choose n-3}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-(n-3)}+{n-2\choose n-3}a_{n-2}k^{n-2-(n-3)}+{n-3\choose n-3}a_{n-3}k^{n-3-(n-3)}\right]\times x^{n-3}\\&\cdots\end{align}

If these expressions are multiplied through and we carry out the column approach once more, we will see that, for example, the sum of all $a_n$ terms is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_nk^{n-j}x^j$. Generalizing, if we look at the sum of all $a_{\tau}$ terms (where $\tau$ is fixed), we have: $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{\tau}a_{\tau}k^{\tau-j}x^j$. And if we look at the sum of all possible sums (as $\tau$ ranges from $0$ to $n$)...which, note, is just $\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_jx^j$... we have:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_jx^j=\sum_{\tau=0}^n \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\tau}a_{\tau}k^{\tau-j}x^j\right)=\sum_{\tau=0}^n a_{\tau}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\tau}k^{\tau-j}x^j\right)$$

By definition, though, $\sum_{j=0}^{\tau}k^{\tau-j}x^j=(k+x)^{\tau}$, so we have that:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_jx^j=\sum_{\tau=0}^n a_{\tau}(k+x)^{\tau}$$

From our previous comments about $f(x)=g(x-k) \iff f(x+k)=g(x)$, we see that the above statement...which can be read as:

$$b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1x^1+b_0=a_n(x+k)^n+a_{n-1}(x+k)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(x+k)^1+a_0$$

is logically equivalent to the statement:

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x^1+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)^1+b_0$$

As such, I've proven here that $\theta(B,k,A,n) \implies \psi(B, f, k, A, n)$, which, given the initial proof, really means $\theta(B,k,A,n) \iff \psi(B, f, k, A, n)$. Hence, the backwards strategy I originally used *is* valid...but only because I was able to demonstrate that $\theta(B,k,A,n) \implies \psi(B, f, k, A, n)$.

Comment: I haven't read all of your answer yet, but it seems to me that it is too complicated. Expanding $g(x) = f(x+k)$ with the binomial theorem gives $g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j x^j$ with some coefficients $b_j$, and then $f(x) = g(x-k) =  \sum_{j=0}^n b_j (x-k)^j$.

Comment: @MartinR I should have mentioned that I was concerned my proof was too complicated! Thank you for this much more concise version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof and the result are correct. Instead of taking derivatives one can also use the binomial theorem:
$$
 g(x) = f(x+k) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x+k)^i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \left(\sum_{j=0}^i \binom i j k^{i-j} x^j \right) \\
= \sum_{j=0}^n \left( \sum_{i=j}^n \binom i j k^{i-j} a_i\right) x^j
= \sum_{j=0}^n b_j x^j
$$
with
$$
 b_j = \sum_{i=j}^n \binom i j k^{i-j} a_i \quad (0 \le j \le n) \,.
$$
Then $f(x) = g(x-k) =  \sum_{j=0}^n b_j (x-k)^j$.

If the concrete values of the coefficients $b_j$ are not needed, only their existence, then it suffices to observe that the $(n+1)^\text{th}$ derivative of $g(x) = f(x+k)$ is zero (by the chain rule), so that $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add the following simple proof, which uses some more powerful tools that I recently learned. Taylor's Theorem states the following:

> Suppose that $f^{(1)}, f^{(2)}, \cdots, f^{(n+1)}$ are all defined on $[a,b]$ and $x \in (a,b]$. Then we have that \begin{align}f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f^{(1)}(a)}{1!}(x-a)^1+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}\end{align} for some $t \in (a,x)$

Using this theorem, we can quickly produce a proof. Let $f$ be any $n$-degree polynomial. Then we know that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and is infinitely differentiable. More specifically, for any $x \in \mathbb R$ and any $k \gt n: f^{(k)}(x)=0$.

Therefore, using Taylor's Theorem, we quickly arrive at:

$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f^{(1)}(a)}{1!}(x-a)^1+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

where all of the coefficients are immediately known.