# Clarifying which instances constitute begging the question when reasoning backwards

Tags: logic, proof-writing

The purpose of this post is to address my incomplete understanding of the logical fallacy '*Begging the Question*'.

Proofs come in many different flavors...and one flavor (backwards reasoning) that can 'fake you out' into thinking that you are *begging the question* can be demonstrated in the following example:

> Find all numbers $x$ for which $4-x \lt 3 - 2x$.

Questions like this usually start with the conclusion and then work backwards to arrive at the relevant information. For example, $4-x \lt 3 - 2x \implies (-4)+4-x+(2x) \lt (-4)+3-2x + (2x)$. This expression simplifies to:

$$4-x \lt 3 - 2x \implies x \lt -1$$

My understanding as to why this is **not** begging the question is that all of the algebraic steps we performed are perfectly reversible. For example, if we, instead, *start* with $x \lt -1$, then we can argue: $x \lt -1 \implies (-2x)+x+(4) \lt(-2x)-1+(4)$. This expression simplifies to:

$$x \lt -1 \implies4-x \lt 3-2x$$

So, in actuality, we have: $x \lt -1 \iff 4-x \lt 3-2x $. It is my current (but perhaps incorrect) understanding that the biconditional nature of these statements...$x \lt -1$ and $4-x \lt3-2x$...allows us to start with the conclusion and work backwards to arrive at our desired answer. As such, we are not really begging the question because to start with the conclusion is logically equivalent to starting with the antecedent.

If the above is correct, then I would like to move on towards the primary purpose of this post:

---

I recently posted a proof ([For any function $f$ that is a "polynomial in $x$", an equivalent representation of $f$ can be made such that it is, instead, a "polynomial in $x-k$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831447/for-any-function-f-that-is-a-polynomial-in-x-an-equivalent-representation)) that was deemed correct by a reputable user. Briefly, I wanted to prove that:

> For any $n$-degree polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ and for any non-zero $k \in \mathbb R$, there exists a collection $b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_{n-1},b_n$ such that $f(x)=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0$

Using backwards reasoning, I first started with the conclusion:

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0$$

Using some basic calculus, I came up with the following procedure to calculate any $b_j$:

1. Take the $j$th derivative of both sides
2. Evaluate both sides at $x=k$
3. After some algebraic simplifications, you get: $$b_j={n\choose j}a_nk^{n-j}+{n-1\choose j}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}+\cdots+{j+1\choose j}a_{j+1}k+{j\choose j}a_j$$

Done. That's all I wrote...and that's how I ended the proof. Now my question is...**why is this valid?**

To be absolutely precise, shouldn't I have to subsequently show that:

\begin{align}&\forall j \in \{0,1,\cdots,n\}: b_j={n\choose j}a_nk^{n-j}+{n-1\choose j}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}+\cdots+{j+1\choose j}a_{j+1}k+{j\choose j}a_j \implies \\&a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0 \end{align}

If NO, then why? Is it because the differentiation operation (part of my proof) has an inverse in the form of integration...and is therefore reversible? (much like in the original example above that had addition vs subtraction)? And, therefore, I ultimately have the biconditional:

\begin{align} &\forall j \in \{0,1,\cdots,n\}: b_j={n\choose j}a_nk^{n-j}+{n-1\choose j}a_{n-1}k^{n-1-j}+\cdots+{j+1\choose j}a_{j+1}k+{j\choose j}a_j\\&\iff \\ &a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=b_n(x-k)^n+b_{n-1}(x-k)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1(x-k)+b_0 \end{align}

Or is there some other reason that my proof is valid...despite starting with the consequent?